Getting error 503 when doing basic database calls in Entity Framework Core and SQL Server
I have an issue where my solution runs fine when using Visual Studio, but when I publish to IIS, the site loads at first, but when I reload the page it fails with 503. After some research I found out it is caused by too many exceptions.
I've debugged and figured out it fails after selecting data from the database, but why? When stepping over the returned data is as expected and theres no exceptions.
There's no entry in the event logs or local log files.
I've implemented Serilog, but there's no issues logged, just Information that all is ok.
It's so weird it works perfect while being debugged, but fails on the server.
I installed Visual Studio on the server and same result, it worked in VS.
Config (extension model):
internal static IServiceCollection AddDB(this IServiceCollection services) => services
.AddDbContext(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(AssetsStatics.ConnectionString))
DbContext:
public interface IAssetsDbContext
{
    DbSet<App> App { get; set; }
    DbSet<AppType> AppType { get; set; }
    DbSet<Secret> Secret { get; set; }
    DbSet<Models.Client> Client { get; set; }
    DbSet<Culture> Culture { get; set; }
    DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
}

public class AssetsDbContext : DbContext, IAssetsDbContext
{
    public AssetsDbContext() : base()
    {

    }

    public AssetsDbContext(DbContextOptions<AssetsDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(AssetsStatics.ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<App>().ToTable("App");
        builder.Entity<AppType>().ToTable("AppType");
        builder.Entity<Secret>().ToTable("Secret");
        builder.Entity<Models.Client>().ToTable("Client");
        builder.Entity<Culture>().ToTable("Culture");
        builder.Entity<Country>().ToTable("Country");
    }

    public DbSet<App> App { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppType> AppType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Secret> Secret { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Client> Client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Culture> Culture { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
}

If I do a simple call like:
var test = await dbContext.App.SingleAsync(a => a.Id == 1);

Everything works when debugging, but fails when running on IIS.
Site when debugging:

Site when published:

Site when published and reloaded:


HTTP 503 means the target service is unavailable, it doesn't necessarily mean your application has crashed (in my case, we rarely get false negatives back from the health check API, which results in 503). Have you tried any of the solutions suggested here?

Do u have in code any  preprocessor directives #if DEBUG #else #endif and when u deploy it goes in Release mode and some other code is executed? I know i forgot once about this piece of code and spent hours to figure it out.

I think it falls under app pools rapid-fail protection. but I just created a new db context, new database on the same server and a simple model. and it worked! so now I think I might have to check my models design. simplify it

@DA believe me I have checked and doubled checked, but no. but now I'm happy that the new test db context seems to work. so I'll recreate the original db context and all the models

There must be something in a log somewhere, unless you are catching and swallowing exceptions

Did you check the IIS logs? It could be something related with the certificates used in IIS.

@AzzyElvul believe me I've checked everything. Every event log, local iis log's, debugged every line of code from startup, middleware, and everything I could think of. I nailed it down to the database call, but why has been hard to figure out

If the code worked when debugging with VS and failed when running in IIS then one thing to check is if your connection string is using Windows auth (Trusted_Connection) vs. SQL Auth. With Windows Auth in IIS it will be trying to connect to the DB using whatever account your App Pool is setup to use and that may be getting rejected by the database server. You will want the app pool using a designated account and enable that account to have permissions to connect to the DB and read/write data as necessary.

Hi @SteinLundbeckTech, Review any specific configurations in OnModelCreating (e.g., key configurations, data annotations, or foreign key constraints) to ensure they match the actual database schema. Mismatches here could cause hidden exceptions.

Besides, Since standard logs aren’t showing any issues, enabling detailed logging on database queries might reveal unexpected errors:builder.Services.AddDbContext<MvcProjContext>(options =>     options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcProjContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'MvcProjContext' not found."))     .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()     .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information));

Do you have a version of the ASP.NET Core Runtime (and the hosting bundle) installed on the IIS server that supports the version your solution is targeting?

"Site when published and reloaded:" - but the address says localhost. I thought you'd put this on some real prod server somewhere, like Azure/AWS

Could you please check the .NET version in your IIS pool is same as your dev .NET version. If its different install relevant version and try again.

As I know, .NET version in IIS can be compatible, but not the same. In my IIS I just turn on last available version of ASP.NET. It would be nice to provide screenshot image in your answer.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
