How to use multiple DbContexts in same query expression in Entity Framework Core
Is it possible to use two DbContext in the same query?
I have different DbContexts that have different tables in the same database. The tables have schema name after the DbContext.
In DbContextOne, I have a model called App, which many other tables reference, but how can I include App in queries for models in a different DbContext?
DbContextOne:
{
    public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<App> App { get; set; }
}

DbContextTwo:
{
    public DbSet<WebSite> WebSite { get; set; }
    public DbSet<View> View { get; set; }
}

WebSite model:
public class WebSite : DbSecureKey, IWebSite
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string? TitleSeparator { get; set; } = null;
    public string? BaseUrl { get; set; } = null;
}

My standard query expression when using only one DbContext:
context.GetWorker<WebSite>().DbSet
            .Include(st => st.App)
                .ThenInclude(app => app.Client)
            .Include(st => st.Options)
            .Include(st => st.Cultures)
                .ThenInclude(clt => clt.Culture);
            

How should I modify my query expression?

What are you trying to achieve ? You should store it in a memory, but why won't you merge into a single dbcontext obj ?

@AVTUNEY I'm trying to load App from AppId from a table in a different dbcontext. I didn't know I could merge them. I'll check it out, thanks!

That wasn't what AVTUNEY asked. There's no good reason to use 2 DbContexts in the same query - you can't do it anyway. If you find yourself in that situation, the application design is wrong. A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work containing ALL the entities needed in a specific use case/domain context. If you want to use the same entities in different use cases, you can use them in different DbContexts

@PanagiotisKanavos I've moved away from my initial approach and just return App when needed, and not in the query expressions

Where and how is EF used anyway? EF has no GetWorker. We can't guess what those custom methods are doing. If you want to use the same tables or entities in different use cases/contexts, you can. You can also map the same table to different entities in different DbContexts. After all, you don't treat a Customer the same way in an e-Shop's catalog and the Fulfillment service. A Product in the catalog has sizes, prices etc while in the Procurement it has suppliers, palet sizes, lead times etc

@PanagiotisKanavos why would you need to know that? Everything regarding my question is present, like tables and my normal query expression. All I was asking if there was some way to use two db contexts in one query expression, and now I know this is stupid

The question itself is wrong and shows a misunderstanding of how EF works, what DbContext  is and how it's used. There's absolutely no reason to have 2 DbContexts. 1st, because you can have all the entities you need in a single context and 2) because the DbContext is a Unit-of-Work. That single context detects and saves all changes in the objects it tracks. That's impossible to do if you had 2 DbContexts. You'd need another class doing what DbContext does right now

@PanagiotisKanavos I have a system where I define features, and each feature has its own dbcontext. so far it's been working pretty great. it's not against any rule of EF. I had a solution with one big dbcontext,  and when it broke it was very hard to debug, so this time I'm trying it this way. if it turns out it doesn't work I'll go back to a single context

You could perhaps execute some sql raw to pull data in from the other tables your EF doesn't know about, just it's kinda jank

If you're accustomed to making a context per feature maybe just make another context to solve this. Tell us more about your debugging woes; we might be able to offer tips. I didn't find it significantly more difficult to debug a 300 table contexts compared to a 10 table one

@flackoverstow well I got this library which takes care of many standard web site things, like meta values and titles. Suddenly it all stopped working. no logs, no exception. I could locate one event where the exception stacktrace showed that the error was in the data layer. To be honest I don't know where it failed since it worked fine when running through Visual Studio, but failed when I published. I even installed VS on the server and it worked fine there too. So it's for easier locating errors. As mentioned, if it doesn't seem to work I'll go back to single context

@flackoverstow I created a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79154398/getting-error-503-when-doing-basic-database-calls-in-entity-framework-core-and-s

@SteinTech if you need to use two contexts in one query, the design is unworkable. LINQ queries are made against the entities in a single Unit-of-Work, ie DbContext, I got this library which takes care of many standard web site things if it's Boilerplate, it won't be the only bad design. The plethora of CRUD classes over DbContexts is a one well known problem causing perf issues. Many of the "features" only exist to claim the library follows the latest "best practices". Just because a library claims to follow "best practices" or DDD or whatever doesn't mean it does, or does it well

Query using DbContextOne
var apps = contextOne.App.ToList(); // Load all apps
or
Query using DbContextTwo
or
Merge Results in Memory

It may work, but I suspect it isn't an optimal way to do it. However your point is valid ..

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
